# Set properties for a cell in a heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i have a question about the heatmap from Highcharts js. I currently using version 4.0.4 for Highcharts. The question is very simple. Can i set properties for a cell for example the color in Highcharts. I can't find anything in their docs.

```
"data":[[0,0,"1"],[1,0,1342],[0,1,"2"],[1,1,127]
```

Here are some data for a heat map object. My idea was to set the properties like this:

```
"data":[[[0, 0, 10], {color : green}],[1,0,1342],[0,1,"2"],[1,1,127]
```

But it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close.

The reason that's not working for you is that you're trying to mix object and array notations.

Instead of

```
[[0, 0, 10], {color : green}]
```

You need

```
{x:0,y:0,value:10,color:'green'}
```

If you name one parameter explicitly, name them all.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/p7v2f117/